# What does it mean to fit "working set" into RAM for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB is fast, but only when your working set or index can fit into RAM. So if my server has 16G of RAM, does that mean the sizes of all my collections need to be less than or equal to 16G? How does one say "ok this is my working set, the rest can be "archived?"

Comment: FYI, to estimate the current size of the working set, run: "db.runCommand( { serverStatus: 1, workingSet: 1 } )". Per docs,  "The working set for a MongoDB database is the portion of your data that clients access most often" http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/diagnostics/

Comment: DocumentDB doesn't seem to support the `workingSet` command.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

"Working set" is basically the amount of data AND indexes that will be active/in use by your system.

So for example, suppose you have 1 year's worth of data. For simplicity, each month relates to 1GB of data giving 12GB in total, and to cover each month's worth of data you have 1GB worth of indexes again totalling 12GB for the year.

If you are always accessing the last 12 month's worth of data, then your working set is: 12GB (data) + 12GB (indexes) = 24GB.

However, if you actually only access the last 3 month's worth of data, then your working set is: 3GB (data) + 3GB (indexes) = 6GB. In this scenario, if you had 8GB RAM and then you started regularly accessing the past 6 month's worth of data, then your working set would start to exceed past your available RAM and have a performance impact.

But generally, if you have enough RAM to cover the amount of data/indexes you expect to be frequently accessing then you will be fine.

**Edit: Response to question in comments**
I'm not sure I quite follow, but I'll have a go at answering. Firstly, the calculation for working set is a "ball park figure". Secondly, if you have a (e.g.) 1GB index on user_id, then only the portion of that index that is commonly accessed needs to be in RAM (e.g. suppose 50% of users are inactive, then 0.5GB of the index will be more frequently required/needed in RAM). In general, the more RAM you have, the better especially as working set is likely to grow over time due to increased usage. This is where sharding comes in - split the data over multiple nodes and you can cost effectively scale out. Your working set is then divided over multiple machines, meaning the more can be kept in RAM. Need more RAM? Add another machine to shard on to.

Comment: Thanks for using examples ;-) ... What if the site is something along the lines of let's say a social networking site. (Let's not debate about whether NoSQL is the right tool for the job, etc...). You have millions of users, that's gotta be a huge table I assume. How would you define working set? I guess my question is, how do you define a working set? If I index "user_id," obviously that entails a user collection for all my users. I can't specify, only pull users from 3 months ago, could I?

Comment: @luckytaxi - I've (hopefully) answered a bit more in my update above!

Comment: Doh, forgot about sharding. I guess my question was more towards "how do you tell mongo to keep the following data as your 'working set?'" If 50% of users are inactive, how do you NOT load that into RAM?

Comment: @luckytaxi - it comes down to what is actually being queried. Generally speaking, if older data is not being accessed, then it won't be pulled into RAM. So it's more what is being accessed/queried as opposed to you telling it what data you want in your working set....if you see what I mean?!

Comment: Ohhhh, that makes sense then. haha ... hence the term "working data." This whole time I thought you had to modify the collection somehow to put certain records before others. Thanks man!

Comment: So, if your working set does **not** fit into RAM, but your index **does** fit, then you'll have fast look-ups, but slow retrievals of the matching documents since you need to go to disk? In other words,  your index is in RAM, but your actual documents are not. So you need to fetch them from disk. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: "...then only the portion of that index that is commonly accessed needs to be in RAM...". How does MongoDB determine the commonly accessed data? Is it the data accessed atleast once today / past week / past month or any similar logic?

Comment: can someone explain how the size of index can be on the same order of magnitude as size of data in the above example (both 1GB each)? Isn't there more data in all the rows than there are indices in a normal use case scenario? Unless we say that each row of MongoDB can have unique index?

Answer (score 9):

The working set is basically the stuff you are using most (frequently). If you use index A for collection B to search for a subset of documents then you could consider that your working set. As long as the most commonly used parts of those structures can fit in memory then things will be exceedingly fast. As parts no longer fit in your working set, like many of the documents then that can slow down. Generally things will become much slower if your indexes exceed your memory.

Yes, you can have lots of data, where most of it is "archived" and rarely used without affecting the performance of our application or impacting your working set (which doesn't include that archived data).