# MongoDB heavy read,relatively low writes, small operations performance

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance, nosql

I am building an app where I will have schema-less objects. So it makes sense to use mongoDB rather than mysql since mysql will involve multiple tables lookups to assemble an object. I expect my objects to be small in size. ***I just have few questions regarding MongoDB's performance with these tasks***:

1-) **Heavy reading based only on primary ID lookups**: So I won't be using any secondary 'where' statements, only lookups given document ID arrays (of course with primary indexes for document keys).

2-) **Writes for new entries**: I will be writing each new entry as a document. ( Do not expect this to be very heavy).

3-) **Small operations on existing documents**: Increment an integer nested inside a document, or a check if value exists in an array nested inside a document, add a new entry to a list etc.

Based on your knowledge or experience, How would mongoDB perform given these tasks?

Thanks in advance.

I have been told that this question is vague, and I am not sure why. I am asking how well mongoDB is designed to handle these operations in general.

Comment: In "general" MongoDB handles them well.

Comment: generally, yes, MongoDB will kill this stuff (in the good way) - you could make your question better by providing *more* insight into expected document sizes, collection sizes (document count, that is), frequency of reads/writes etc, and even the language/s (and therefore drivers) you will be using around MongoDB - probably many of us who can give more concrete experiences, but only based on specifics in your question

Comment: MongoDB will handle this scenario well. That said, you will want to make sure that you have enough RAM to keep your working set in memory (meaning the records you access most often reside in memory allowing for quick access). See the following link for more information on working sets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb

Comment: and i'm assuming MongoDB handles figuring out the working set based on the frequency of queries, like caching in mysql?

Answer (score 2):

for informations on the working set (and the memory mapping mechanism in general), please, see the FAQ at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-is-the-working-set

Another useful source of information on how to efficiently set up MongoDB is the http://info.10gen.com/rs/10gen/images/10gen-MongoDB_Operations_Best_Practices.pdf

Does this help?

Cheers

Ronald