# MongoDB database partitioning

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I've read about MongoDB concurrency and db-wide write lock.

And I have a question. Is it normal practice to store one logical database in different MongoDB databases?

For example, I have collections, which would be updated very rarely, but read operations would be performed on them very-very often. Is it OK to store them in different database?

What are disadvantages of that practice?

Comment: This answer has been gone over a couple of times however, it is extremely rare that you would ever have the need to optimise to separate databases for one logical database and normally it would create far more complexity than is needed, not only that but it is micro-opitmisation and pre-optimisation

Comment: I would add that for a read-heavy load the most important factor will be having enough RAM to keep your working set in memory. See this SO post for details on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

It's always okay to store things in different databases, but it's unlikely that it is going to help you. Even although MongoDB has database level locking (2.2/2.4), it also employs aggressive yielding when it detects that a page fault (slow "Read from disk) is about to happen. When it detects this, it will yield the write lock so that reads can proceed. Having lots of reads with concurrent writes isn't as much of a problem as you may think. h

The only way how you can make sure that slow "reads from disk" don't happen so often is by making sure that your whole working set fits in RAM. [What does it mean to fit "working set" into RAM for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb) has a great explanation for that.