# MongoDB - Different query execution times after restarting server

Tags: mongodb, profiling

Say that I start a mongo db server:

`mongo --dbpath=/some/path --port=12345 --storageEngine wiredTiger`

I then run a the same query 10 times (disregarding the first one, so that they are all on warm cache) as follows:

`mongo query1.js`

The times that I get are (as verified via `time` and also the mongodb logger):

`8137ms
8145ms
8193ms
8091ms
8152ms
8110ms
8182ms
8142ms
8133ms
8098ms`

Great -- pretty consistent. All are within ~100ms of eachother, which makes sense.

I then shutdown the server, in **any** of the following fashions:

`pkill mongod
mongod --dbpath=/some/path --shutdown
mongo shutdown.js`

Where `shutdown.js` contains:

`db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer();`

I then restart it, using the exact same command, and I get the following times:

`8531ms
8492ms
8613ms
8555ms
8538ms
8512ms
8551ms
8511ms
8608ms
8522ms`

Again, they are consistently within ~100ms, but they are all at a different *baseline*.

If I do this again, it might be around `8.3`, `8.6`, `8.9`, or anywhere in between really. No other user processes are open (except those needed to ssh into the machine).

I ran an experiment as follows:

`while True:
    run the query 25 times and record the minimum such runtime
    shutdown the server and restart it, wait for it to listen`

This ran for two days over the weekend while I did not interact with the machine, collecting 223 data points, and the minimum runtimes ranged from `7.9s` to `8.9s`. If I did not shutdown the server in between, **this does not happen**, but again, I might get a baseline of `7.9s` or I might get one of `8.9s`.

The standard deviation of one data point (the runtimes of the 25 queries) was always really low (around 0.06), but between all queries, was really high.

Does anybody have intuition on why this is happening and how I can prevent it? I am trying to figure out if one query is faster than another, but I can't get a good baseline to test against. Restarting the server is not absolutely necessary, but it would make my life easier, since I do not always have the server running.

Comment: These queries should all be logged as part of slow query logging in the mongod log file. Can you confirm whether the same index is being used by each batch?

Comment: This particular query is an aggregate that only does a $group and then sorts it, so an index is not used at all (it must do a COLLSCAN). I am not sure if this effects anything. By the way, I verified the number of instructions and cache misses via Valgrind. I get a variance of about 0.005% on instruction counts (half a percent) and negligible cache changes, where as query times can vary by as much as 6%, even though they vary only by about a percent within one start of the server. It's very strange.

Comment: Are you starting mongod disabling numactl?  What's the exact version of mongod, of OS, filesystem, etc?

Comment: No, I did not disable numactl. The version of mongoDB is 3.0.7 from Github (compiled by me) on Ubuntu 14.04 built with `scons -j4 --use-system-tcmalloc mongod`. The data is on ext4 filesystem and the mongodb binary is on a nfs fileserver. I *do* get a warning that `/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage_defrag` is set to always.

Comment: Which OS is mogo db running on?

Comment: What results do you get for the query you want to compare?  Does it vary with shutdowns?  and is it always a fixed difference from the main one?

Comment: The results are always the same. This is running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Curious. What happens if you [preheat the data and/or indices](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/touch/)?

Comment: Ah, forget about it – does not apply to WT.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB uses cache for serving some queries as you go. When you restart server, some cache must be clears out. MongoDB keeps all of the most recently used data in RAM. If you have created indexes for your queries and your working data set fits in RAM, MongoDB serves all queries from memory.

**Query plans** are saved in cache which clears out on mongo restart. So it takes time when you run query first time. See explain("executionStats").

With **WiredTiger**, MongoDB utilizes both the filesystem cache and WiredTiger cache. By default, starting in MongoDB 3.2, the WiredTiger cache will use 60% of RAM minus 1 GB or it will use 1 GB, whichever is larger. For systems with up to 10 GB of RAM, this is less than or equal to the 3.0 setting. For systems with more than 10 GB of RAM, the configuration is greater than the 3.0 setting.

In MongoDB 3.0, the WiredTiger cache, by default, uses either 1 GB or half of the installed physical RAM, whichever is larger.

MongoDB also automatically uses all free memory on the machine via the filesystem cache (data in the filesystem cache is compressed).

See for [MongoDB Fundamentals](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/)

Comment: If cache was the problem, shouldn't that eventually be figured out after running the query a few times to warm the cache? Also, the entire database fits in memory both times (about 30% of RAM), so there is plenty of space left for the cache.

Comment: Do you got the answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB keeps the current processing data in RAM so your query request may take different time in same request. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534628/understand-mongodb-cache-system) will help you.