# How to apply aggregate query on cached data. Data is cached using cachegoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, caching, mongoose, redis

I am using cache-goose to cache almost 50,000 to 60,000 data (which may increase). Data is stored successfully in that cache. But after fetching that data from cache, i want to run aggregate query on it. How am i supposed to do that ?

I want to run aggregate query because i want to only display data according to the date selected by user.
Any other suggestions for cache is also welcome.

Comment: Did you check RedisGears?

Comment: Will it be helpful to execute aggregates in MongoDB and save results in cache?

Comment: @AminShojaei No because user can give multiple requests and can select any date

Answer (score 1):

The cache systems don't support aggregation, But MongoDB  supports similar solution.

MongoDB will store last-used data in RAM and serve your requests from there, If you give enough RAM.

Read more: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534847/8712494