# MongoDB Cache or Not Cache using Redis

Tags: mongodb, caching, redis, mongodb-query, spring-data-redis

In my project, main database is mongodb and for caching, i have redis. 
Now for long and more complex queries, it is obviously better that i use redis to cache them.

But i'm wondering if i should cache simple queries like lookup by id, or lookup by some other mongodb indexed field? Does it make sense to use redis for this kind of indexed lookup ?

or should i just not cache this kind of query because mongodb already has good caching mechanism internally?

Is it faster looking up to mongodb indexed field or is it faster to lookup to redis?

Answer (score 5):

1. Lookup in Redis is **definitely faster** (because of the key-value nature of Redis).
2. MongoDB Can't cache **queries' results**:

MongoDB is a Database and can't cache the result of queries for you because data may change anytime. **So managing the cache is the responsibility of the Developer**.

But also the MongoDB has some good internal mechanisms to use the RAM for better performance. (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534847/8712494) Question for more info)

3. DataBase query is **expensive**:

When you are executing a query in MongoDB, there will be many processes to find data, even on simple queries. But Redis can find a key very, very fast. So it's clear that you must use **Redis for keeping things** and use **MongoDB only for permanent storage and queries**.

**My recommendation:**

It's recommended to cache any **high-usage** or **heavy** query's results in the Redis, Memcached, or other key-value in-memory storage.
(It doesn't make sense to look up a simple post in Database/MongoDB a thousand times per day. It's just wasting of resources. The first duty of Cache systems is to keep high-usage data closer)

Also attention you must have a good "[cache invalidation](https://codeahoy.com/2017/08/11/caching-strategies-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one)" mechanism to update cached data in Redis.

I recommend **use the [write-through](https://codeahoy.com/2017/08/11/caching-strategies-and-how-to-choose-the-right-one)** technique to keep models and data in Redis.

I hope this helps.

Comment: even for indexed look up, find document by id? i thought mongodb has some LRU caching as well..

Comment: base on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534847/8712494 . I think if you are sure the result of your query will serve from RAM, then it's not necessary to keep them in Redis. but it's just about simple find(using id), In other cases(when query is longer) personally i will store them in Redis(even when the Database is fast enough, i prefer to don't use database, and keep it light) @user1955934

Comment: is it a good idea to just have very short cache like a minute? worst case is you do 60 calls to db per hour?

Comment: It's fine, even 3 second is find. You should count total of queries and see bigger picture. for example, cache 1000 query which you call them 100/h per each, will save ~99900 Mongo query per hour. @user1955934