# How do i know the size of my mongodb collections so that i can compare that with RAM Size

Tags: mongodb

When i googled for MongoDB best pratices , i found out that , the size of collection in mongodb must be smaller when compared to RAM Size of the CPU 
I have got 6 collections in my mongodb Database .

Please tell me how can i know the size of collections present in MongoDB

The status for one of my collection is

```
db.chains.stats()
{
        "ns" : "at.chains",
        "count" : 2967,
        "size" : 89191980,
        "avgObjSize" : 30061.33468149646,
        "storageSize" : 335118080,
        "numExtents" : 18,
        "nindexes" : 3,
        "lastExtentSize" : 67136000,
        "paddingFactor" : 1.0099999999999996,
        "flags" : 1,
        "totalIndexSize" : 34742272,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 155648,
                "symbol_1" : 172032,
                "unique_symbol_1" : 34414592
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Do i need to sum up the size of all the 6 collections i got and compare that with the RAM Size ??

Or is there any other way ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need call `db.stats();` in Mongodb console, [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#what-tools-can-i-use-to-investigate-storage-use-in-mongodb) is the Mongodb website about your question.

```
> db.stats();
{
    "db" : "test",
    "collections" : 5,
    "objects" : 24,
    "avgObjSize" : 67.33333333333333,
    "dataSize" : 1616,
    "storageSize" : 28672,
    "numExtents" : 5,
    "indexes" : 4,
    "indexSize" : 32704,
    "fileSize" : 201326592,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the size of your collection (chains) by looking at the "size" value. The 89191980 is in bytes, so it's roughly 85 MB. You can find the documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collStats/

It'd be a good idea to take a look at this SO thread, they do a good job of covering RAM size & "working set".

[What does it mean to fit "working set" into RAM for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks for the answer , so i need to add the size value of all my six collections know ? Thanks in advance .

Comment: @PreethiJain read that link he has posted about "working set". Short answer, it depends on your application.