# Optimizing MongoDB for reads

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using MongoDB as a read only document source, used for computing statistics.  Each document has no subdocuments, but the database has approximately ~900k documents and will grow by ~ 1k documents each day, added at a time where the database will be idle.

So, I'd like to understand the following things:

1. I've read that MongoDB works best when the entire collection is stored in RAM. Assuming my database is ~400MB and our server can easily cram the whole thing into RAM, is there a way I can tell MongoDB to pre-load my entire collection into RAM?
2. I've also read that there are cases where creating replica sets will help with the read performance of the database.  Is my scenario one of the cases where this will help?
3. I'm threading my statistical calculations, but notice that the amount of time to complete the queries I run against mongoDB when doing these calculations triples when I thread them as opposed to running them synchronously.  Is there anything I can do to improve the performance of the DB when I'm making requests against the same collection simultaneously?

Comment: When you have multiple questions, please open a new question for each of them. When someone could answer one of the three questions, but not all of them, they wouldn't write an answer because it would be downvoted for being incomplete.

Comment: The MongoDB documentation can help you: http://docs.mongodb.org/master/administration/optimization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About Point 1:

You can use the [touch command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) to persuade the database to load a collection into memory. But keep in mind that this isn't permanent. When you don't access the cached documents soon, they will get uncached in favor of more frequently-used documents.

### About Point 2 and 3:

Replica-sets are a good way to improve the performance of parallel read operations. Each server of a replica-set mirrors the whole data and can respond to any query on its own without having to contact the other servers. That means when you double the number of servers in your replica-set, you also double the performance of simultaneous queries.

Keep in mind that the [read preferences](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) you set on your connection might prevent it from using more than one server.

Alternatively you can build a sharded cluster, but this is technically a lot more complex than a replica-set and won't improve read-performance much when your queries don't match the shard-key of the collection or when you selected your shard-key in a way that the requests aren't evenly distributed between the shards.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great place to get me started!

Comment: what do you mean "no way to do this" - there is the touch command: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/

Comment: replica sets are for HA and failover. they are not a way to scale reads.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky thank you, I didn't know about touch. Answer edited.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Improving reliability is only one reason to use replica-sets. You can use replica-sets to scale reads by having multiple secondaries and distributing reads among them.

Comment: that is not a good way to scale reads. if your reads are slow it's either because of bad indexes (more secondaries won't help) or indexes not fitting in RAM (they won't fit in RAM on secondaries either) or too many writes competing (secondaries do exactly as many writes as primaries).   Replica sets are not for scaling reads.

Answer (score 3):

No, MongoDB DOES NOT WORK BEST when the collection is in RAM. I have no idea who told you that but it is a common mis-conception about how MongoDB works.

MongoDB works best when it can not only fit your working set into RAM ( [What does it mean to fit "working set" into RAM for MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb) ) but also load it in RAM at significantly great speed. One thing that can help the speed of paging in your working set is the size of your documents.

This is one reason why MongoDB is limited to 16MB, it has been found that sizes greater start to have a seriously detremental performance impact. Basically you spend too much time loading your data from the disk, this is one reason for de-normalisation by logically splitting tables in SQL techs; to make them faster to load.

This means you may have to optimise both the size of the value and the size of the field name to match performance needs for your reads. You will of course also have to match hardware.

Replica sets are not actually designed to help with read performance, they are designed to give your data high availability by making automated failover. The topic you read suggests getting stale reads from secondaries. This, as has been proven (**edit**: since proven is a strong word and this is scenario based I'm going to say "found")  recently, can actually be less performant than using PrimaryPreferred read preference.

As for improving performance we would need stats from you on page faults, IO bottlenecks and general mongostat and top.

Comment: If the entire collection is in RAM, it's better than when it's not entirely in RAM. I kinda think you're saying that's not true. Sure, if disk IO is slow then that can be seriously detrimental to the overall performance. But, if the entire collection could be loaded before users hit the DB ... then, wouldn't that be ideal? There are then lots of other factors that could make queries slow as well of course that could have a significant impact (like lack of indexes).

Comment: @WiredPrairie The OS will rarely hold the entire collection in ram for a prolonged period even if it is small and mongod will of course never pin it to memory, as such it will not actually perform better.

Comment: It's going to be held in memory if it's being used frequently, especially if there's no memory pressure.

Comment: (I upvoted your answer as I do think it's a better answer than the accepted answer ... :)  ).

Comment: "This, as has been proven recently, can actually be less performant" [citation needed]

Comment: @Philipp Self testing, wass gonna add the data but couldn't find it but also Asya on the google group mentioned it, I will pull up the thread

Comment: @Philipp hmm maybe proven is a strong word since it is scenario based