# Does running MongoDB in-memory create duplicates on RAM

Tags: mongodb, memory

You can create ramdisks, tmpfs etc on RAM to create partitions to be used for different applications.

A similar one was posted in the following post: [How to use MongoDB as a pure in-memory DB (Redis style)](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis)

MongoDB uses the resident memory for the hot data.

Hence 
1) Does using ramdisk duplicate the ram usage for the same data?

2) Is there a way to disable the usage of resident memory?

---

**Edit**: We can think of the hosting OS as CentOS or Ubuntu Servers, since they are the foremost used servers.

Comment: There are specialized in-memory databases you could take a look at.

Comment: Interesting question. MongoDB uses memory mapped files, so it might be interesting to find out whether the OS's memory mapping knows that a given file lies in RAM already, or not. This might depend on the operating system and the way the files are allocated. In any case, I think it might be a better idea to use an in-memory database, because the persistence-ensuring part of the code will be there, no matter where the files are stored (i.e. MongoDB itself doesn't know that a file is in a RAM disk).

Comment: MongoDB implements its RAM caching with memory-mapped files which are in turn managed by the operating system. So the question is whether or not your operating system is smart enough to realize that the memory-mapped file is on a ramdisk which means that creating a duplicate of the data in ram is pointless.

Comment: @mnemosyn: This question is easy to answer. For MongoDB the file is not in RAM, even when saved in a RAM disk – it simply has no access to the RAM used by the RAM disk by other means than filesystem related operations. I am pretty sure that this is true for both Windows and all UNIX derivates, including GNU/Linux. However, I strongly second your suggestion of using a dedicated in memory database.

Comment: I know this is an older question, but mongodb will keep the hot data (the "working set") in memory - assuming there is enough.  Say your working set accessing only a small % of the total data then unless you move outside this, the information will be in RAM.  Like previously mentioned, memory mapped so that updates are managed to the disk by the OS.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

By the way MongoDB introduced plug-able storage engines in 3.0 release.
And it ships with an experimental in-memory DB storage engine.

I was planning to use in memory DB for our testing environments, in order to get fast responses. So being experimental seems fine to me.

http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/whats-new-mongodb-30-part-3-performance-efficiency-gains-new-storage-architecture