# Mongodb, working set when less frequent data access great than RAM capacity

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have read the [what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453584/what-does-it-mean-to-fit-working-set-into-ram-for-mongodb). But I am very confuse about the mongodb memory managements. 
Suppose I have a machine with 40G RAM. I use mongo to develop a game, there are two collections.

- user,  this collection keep growing, 1G Data + 0.1G index per month,  but only the portion of users are active, let's assume only 1G data are active. Does this means that this collection will use about 1G + 0.1G * month mem, like it will consume 2G mem when the application online 10 months.
- game_record_${yyyy_MM}, it may contains column like uid, gameId, win, score, time.
  this collection store the game record, the data create when user play game, it is 1:n relationship from user to game_record_${yyyy_MM} collection, this collection keep growing too, 10G data + 1G index per month. And it is sharded by month(sharding program by hand). Let assume the application has online about 10 month, then the total data is 110G. 
  There are collection
- user_game_2018_01
- user_game_2017_12
- user_game_2017_11
- user_game_2017_10
- ...
- user_game_2017_01

The data access schema is just a simple pagination query.

```
db.game_record_${yyyy_MM}.find({uid: 'Kelvin'}).sort({time:-1}).skip(n).limit(10) //n keep update for continuous query
```

the program keep search the data from current to pass.
The questions is:
We assume that most users will only check their latest 3 months data so only three collection of data are active and all fit in memory, it will consume 33G RAM. In the worse case, when some user keep navigate there game data to the oldest, so all the collections are queried. **What happen to mongo, does the oldest collection will fit into memory and swap out the current active collection like user_game_201801**

Answer (score 0):

This problem will not occur in your case because **Mongo keeps indexes in RAM not the collection data**.

So in your case after 10 months you will have 1GB indexes from user collection & 10GB indexes from game_record_{yyyy_MM} collections.

So you have is 11GB indexes i.e. less than your RAM size.

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect: MongoDB uses RAM for both indexes & documents. Document access (reads & writes) happens in-memory for both the default storage engine (WiredTiger) and the legacy MMAP storage engine. The general guidance is to try to size your RAM to accomodate your working set (portion of your data that clients work with most frequently) in order to minimise I/O activity. Data remains in memory on a least-recently-used basis, so older collections and indexes that are rarely (or never) accessed should not be considered part of the working set.

Comment: If a user is allowed to navigate through historical data which isn't part of the planned working set, ideally the application will limit the impact to [covered queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/#covered-queries) where results can be returned only using indexes. Queries that are not covered will result in fetching documents into memory.